# Can I use a if statement to create a currency converter app?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, converters

Im trying to make an app that has a simple currency system that uses copper, silver, and gold, which are worth different values. I want the app to be able to convert one currency to another. The user first enters an amount that they wish to convert. They then select the currency this amount represents and the currency they wish to convert it to. Once they have selected both options, clicking ‘Calculate’ will show the converted cost. Ive started my code but as I am a beginner is the best way to go about this using a if statement for which buttons are selected to convert the currency?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/copperBt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/copperBt1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.151"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.314" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/silverBt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/silverBt1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/goldBt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/goldBt1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.848"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/copperBt2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/copperBt2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.151"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.515" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/silverBt2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/silverBt2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.515" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/goldBt2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/goldBt2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.848"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.515" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculateBt"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/calculateBt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.651" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewFrom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/fromTxt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.257" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/toTxt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.446" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/convertedCostTxt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.742" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/amountTxt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.061" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/editTxt"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.582"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04"
    android:autofillHints="" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my main activity code:

```
package com.currencyconverter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.text.InputType;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button btCopper1 = findViewById(R.id.copperBt1);
    final Button btCopper2 = findViewById(R.id.copperBt2);
    final Button btSilver1 = findViewById(R.id.silverBt1);
    final Button btSilver2 = findViewById(R.id.silverBt2);
    final Button btGold1 = findViewById(R.id.goldBt1);
    final Button btGold2 = findViewById(R.id.goldBt2);
    final Button btCalculate = findViewById(R.id.calculateBt);
    final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editTxt);
    final TextView costTextView = findViewById(R.id.textViewCost);

    btCopper1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btCopper1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a0522d"));

        }
    });

    btCopper2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btCopper2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a0522d"));
        }
    });

    btSilver1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btSilver1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8b8989"));

        }
    });

    btSilver2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btSilver2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8b8989"));

        }
    });

    btGold1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btGold1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#daa520"));

        }
    });

    btGold2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btGold2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#daa520"));

        }
    });

    btCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int num = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());




            costTextView.setText(editText.getText());


        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Instead of using an `if` statement, you should use the concepts of OOP (Object Oriented Programming) and use inheritance to do this kind of action for you. Let's say you have to add 10 more currencies, so 10 new `IF` statements. With inheritance you can have N values that use the same method with 0 IF on your logic.

Comment: Can you use inheritance even if all the currency are different?

Comment: Although the effect is same, I think switch case would look clean here instead of if-else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If statements could get the job done, but using OOP would make the code more efficient and easier to add more currencies down the road.

What you could do is make a class called Currency, and you would initialize a method called something like convert_to(Currency c). To make this method work, you could initialize a dictionary attribute that would store every other currency instance as keys and show their respective exchange rates. You could also add a method called add(Currency c, float exchange_rate) to update your currency's dictionary. When calling the convert method, you would just input the currency to which you wish to convert, and the method could be made to grab the exchange rate stored in the currency's dictionary. You can obviously add more methods to manage your information.